Numba cuda.jit and njit giving different results
In the following example, I have a simple CPU function:
import numpy as np
from numba import njit, cuda

@njit
def cpu_func(a, b, c, d):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for l in range(d[i], 0, -1):
            for j in range(l):
                a[i, j] = (b[i] * a[i, j] + (1.0 - b[i]) * a[i, j + 1]) / c[i]

    return a[:, 0]

and an equivalent GPU implementation of the same function above:
@cuda.jit
def _gpu_func(a, b, c, d, out):
    i = cuda.grid(1)
    if i < len(a):
        for l in range(d[i], 0, -1):
            for j in range(l):
                a[i, j] = (b[i] * a[i, j] + (1.0 - b[i]) * a[i, j + 1]) / c[i]
            out[i] = a[i, 0]

def gpu_func(a, b, c, d):
    d_a = cuda.to_device(a)
    d_b = cuda.to_device(b)
    d_c = cuda.to_device(c)
    d_d = cuda.to_device(d)
    d_out = cuda.device_array(len(a))

    threads_per_block = 64
    blocks_per_grid = 128
    _gpu_func[blocks_per_grid, threads_per_block](d_a, d_b, d_c, d_d, d_out)
    out = d_out.copy_to_host()

    return out

However, when I call BOTH functions with the same inputs, I am getting very different results:
a = np.array([[
    1.150962188573305234e+00, 1.135924188549360281e+00, 1.121074496043255930e+00, 1.106410753047196494e+00, 1.091930631080626046e+00,
    1.077631830820479752e+00, 1.063512081736074144e+00, 1.049569141728566635e+00, 1.035800796774924315e+00, 1.022204860576360286e+00,
    1.008779174211164253e+00, 9.955216057918859773e-01, 9.824300501268078412e-01, 9.695024283856580327e-01, 9.567366877695103744e-01,
    9.441308011848159598e-01, 9.316827669215179686e-01, 9.193906083351972569e-01, 9.072523735331967654e-01, 8.952661350646772265e-01,
    8.834299896145549891e-01, 8.717420577012704452e-01, 8.602004833783417626e-01, 8.488034339396569594e-01, 8.375490996284553624e-01,
    8.264356933499517055e-01, 8.154614503875622367e-01, 8.046246281226814290e-01, 7.939235057579688837e-01, 7.833563840441006842e-01,
    7.729215850099430130e-01, 7.626174516961046201e-01, 7.524423478918242925e-01, 7.423946578751554615e-01, 7.324727861564024334e-01,
    7.226751572247696043e-01, 7.130002152981841368e-01, 7.034464240762497989e-01, 6.940122664962961041e-01, 6.846962444924807878e-01,
    6.754968787579095357e-01, 6.664127085097342196e-01, 6.574422912571935562e-01, 6.485842025725561122e-01, 6.398370358649341227e-01,
    6.311994021569281577e-01, 6.226699298640693270e-01, 6.142472645770222783e-01, 6.059300688465173446e-01, 5.977170219709739829e-01,
    0.000000000000000000e+00
]])
b = np.array([1.533940813369776279e+00])
c = np.array([1.018336794718317062e+00])
d = np.array([50], dtype=np.int64)

cpu_func(a.copy(), b, c, d)  # Produces array([0.74204214])
gpu_func(a.copy(), b, c, d)  # Produces array([0.67937252])

I understand that numerical precision can be an issue (e.g., overflow/underflow) and each compiler may optimize the code differently (e.g., fused multiply-and-add) but, setting that aside for now, is there some way to ensure/force the CPU code and the GPU code to both produce the SAME output (up to 4-5 decimal places)? Or maybe there is some clever way to improve the precision?
Additional Validation
For completeness, I attempted to perform the same computation using the mpmath package which claims to provide fixed precision capabilities:
import mpmath
mpmath.mp.dps = 100  # Precision

def mpmath_cpu_func(a, b, c, d):
    for i in range(a.rows):
        for l in range(d[i], 0, -1):
            for j in range(l):
                a[i, j] = (b[i] * a[i, j] + (1.0 - b[i]) * a[i, j + 1]) / c[i]
    return a[:, 0]

# Convert inputs to mpmath types with high precision
mp_a = mpmath.matrix(a.copy())
for i in range(a.shape[0]):
    for j in range(a.shape[1]):
        mp_a[i, j] = mpmath.mpf(a[i, j].astype(str))
mp_b = [mpmath.mpf(b[0].astype(str))]
mp_c = [mpmath.mpf(c[0].astype(str))]

mpmath_cpu_func(mp_a, mp_b, mp_c, d)  # Produces 0.6449015342958763156413719663014237700252472529553791866336058829452386808983049961922292904843391669

Note that the high precision result is also different from the CPU and GPU results above. Is there is some clever way to improve the precision of the GPU/CPU implementations above? I would be happy to get within 4-5 decimal places of agreement amongst all three versions.
Update

I understand that numerical precision can be an issue (e.g., overflow/underflow) and each compiler may optimize the code differently (e.g., fused multiply-and-add) but, setting that aside for now, is there some way to ensure/force the CPU code and the GPU code to both produce the SAME output (up to 4-5 decimal places)? Or maybe there is some clever way to improve the precision?

I was able to leverage the pyfma package in the CPU code (without numba njit!) to produce a result that matches the GPU code:
import numpy as np
import pyfma
import _pyfma
from numpy.typing import ArrayLike

def monkey_patch_fma(a: ArrayLike, b: ArrayLike, c: ArrayLike) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    This is a simple monkey patch to make `pyfma` compatible with NumPy v2.0

    Based on this `pyfma` PR - https://github.com/nschloe/pyfma/pull/17/files
    """
    a = np.asarray(a)
    b = np.asarray(b)
    c = np.asarray(c)
    # dtype = np.find_common_type([], [a.dtype, b.dtype, c.dtype])
    dtype = np.promote_types(np.promote_types(a.dtype, b.dtype), c.dtype)
    a = a.astype(dtype)
    b = b.astype(dtype)
    c = c.astype(dtype)

    if dtype == np.single:
        return _pyfma.fmaf(a, b, c)
    elif dtype == np.double:
        return _pyfma.fma(a, b, c)

    assert dtype == np.longdouble
    return _pyfma.fmal(a, b, c)

pyfma.fma = monkey_patch_fma

def fma_cpu_func(a, b, c, d):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for l in range(d[i], 0, -1):
            for j in range(l):
                a[i, j] = pyfma.fma(b[i], a[i, j], (1.0 - b[i]) * a[i, j + 1]) / c[i]
    return a[:, 0]

a = np.array([[
    1.150962188573305234e+00, 1.135924188549360281e+00, 1.121074496043255930e+00, 1.106410753047196494e+00, 1.091930631080626046e+00,
    1.077631830820479752e+00, 1.063512081736074144e+00, 1.049569141728566635e+00, 1.035800796774924315e+00, 1.022204860576360286e+00,
    1.008779174211164253e+00, 9.955216057918859773e-01, 9.824300501268078412e-01, 9.695024283856580327e-01, 9.567366877695103744e-01,
    9.441308011848159598e-01, 9.316827669215179686e-01, 9.193906083351972569e-01, 9.072523735331967654e-01, 8.952661350646772265e-01,
    8.834299896145549891e-01, 8.717420577012704452e-01, 8.602004833783417626e-01, 8.488034339396569594e-01, 8.375490996284553624e-01,
    8.264356933499517055e-01, 8.154614503875622367e-01, 8.046246281226814290e-01, 7.939235057579688837e-01, 7.833563840441006842e-01,
    7.729215850099430130e-01, 7.626174516961046201e-01, 7.524423478918242925e-01, 7.423946578751554615e-01, 7.324727861564024334e-01,
    7.226751572247696043e-01, 7.130002152981841368e-01, 7.034464240762497989e-01, 6.940122664962961041e-01, 6.846962444924807878e-01,
    6.754968787579095357e-01, 6.664127085097342196e-01, 6.574422912571935562e-01, 6.485842025725561122e-01, 6.398370358649341227e-01,
    6.311994021569281577e-01, 6.226699298640693270e-01, 6.142472645770222783e-01, 6.059300688465173446e-01, 5.977170219709739829e-01,
    0.000000000000000000e+00
]])
b = np.array([1.533940813369776279e+00])
c = np.array([1.018336794718317062e+00])
d = np.array([50], dtype=np.int64)

fma_cpu_func(a.copy(), b, c, d)  # Produces array([0.67937252])

So, both the CPU and GPU outputs are identical and  "closer" to the higher-precision output (0.644901534295876315641) but still inaccurate.

According to your update, the difference seems to be due to the lack of fma optimization. (Hence my recent comment was completely wrong. Sorry if that caused confusion).
You can enable this feature in jit functions as well with the fastmath option.
@njit(fastmath={"contract"})
def cpu_func_fm(a, b, c, d):
    for i in range(len(a)):
        for l in range(d[i], 0, -1):
            for j in range(l):
                a[i, j] = (b[i] * a[i, j] + (1.0 - b[i]) * a[i, j + 1]) / c[i]

    return a[:, 0]

Result:
cpu_func    : 0.7420421437852579
gpu_func    : 0.6793725228584361
fma_cpu_func: 0.6793725228584361
cpu_func_fm : 0.6793725228584361

